# Turn on led by phone and phone contacts

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I would like ask for help. Can you give me an advice how to create (contacts) nubers who can turn on led.

```
#include <GSM.h>
#define PINNUMBER ""
GSM gsmAccess;
GSMVoiceCall vcs; 
char numtel[20];

void setup()
{
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

Serial.begin(9600);
while (!Serial) {
;
}

Serial.println("Receive Voice Call");

boolean notConnected = true;

while (notConnected)
{
if (gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY)
  notConnected = false;
else
{
  Serial.println("Not connected");
  delay(1000);
}
}

vcs.hangCall();

Serial.println("Waiting for a call");
}

void loop()
{

switch (vcs.getvoiceCallStatus())
{
case IDLE_CALL: 

  break;

case RECEIVINGCALL: 

  Serial.println("RECEIVING CALL");

  vcs.retrieveCallingNumber(numtel, 20);


  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);


  vcs.answerCall();
  vcs.hangCall();
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);

  break;


  }
  delay(1000);
  }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Now when i call to my number arduino do   digitalWrite(13, HIGH); and low after. But i need something as adress book with numbers who when call arduino do  digitalWrite(13, HIGH); afer low and hangcall, but when call something who not is on the list of my contact arduino only hang call. Sorry for my english. And thanks for answer

Comment: I do not know the GSMVoiceCall library, but I assume `retrieveCallingNumber` may return the number of the caller in the string (character array) `numtel`. So you need to compare that against your list of predefined numbers that are allowed to switch the LED. Have a look at http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringComparisonOperators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `retrieveCallingNumber` is documented in [here](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSMVCSRetrieveCallingNumber). It "retrieves the calling number, and stores it" in a character array passed as second argument.

The simplest solution to check if this number is among the allowed ones is to [construct](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringConstructors) a [string](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/String) from this and [compare](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringComparisonOperators) it against a predefined string for equality. (If you have more than one allowed number, repeat for all.)

Something like this:

```
vcs.retrieveCallingNumber(numtel, 20);
String s = String(numtel);
if (s == "allowed number goes here") {
    // toggle LED etc.
}
```